# Почему ProcessBuilder не запускает скрипт сразу?

Tags: java, jar

Есть небольшой планировщик который должен запускать java приложения иcпользуя `java -jar /.../app.jar` через каждую минуту (Запускаемые jar это разные jar'ники и разные приложения их приличный список).

Но проблема в том что скрипты запуска в `ProcessBuilder` не отрабатываются сразу. Или точнее говоря они вообще не отрабатываются до тех пор пока я не закрою этот стартер. И это совсем не то поведение которое я ожидал. 
Я пробовал к вызову `.command("java", "-jar", file).start()` добавить `waitFor()`, но это не как не исправляет ситуацию.

Как мне добиться такого поведения чтобы приложения открывалить по цепочке с задержкой в минуту?

```
Map<String, String> prop = new PropertiesHolder().fetchProperties();
ScheduledExecutorService executorService = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(10);        

AtomicInteger latency = new AtomicInteger(0);
prop.keySet().stream()
        .filter(key -> key.contains("channel"))
        .forEach(channelKey -> {
            latency.set(latency.get() + 60);
            String dir = prop.get(channelKey);
            Runnable task = taskFactory(dir, "app.jar");
            executorService.schedule(task, latency.get(), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        });

private static Runnable taskFactory(final String dir, final String file) {
    return () -> new Starter().start(dir, file);
}

public class Starter {
    public void start(String dir, String file) {
        try {
            new ProcessBuilder().directory(new File(dir)).command("java", "-jar", file).start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```